# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 Answers: Granular Aggregation in Hierarchy - Versioning

Tags: analytics, hierarchy, business-intelligence, obiee, granularity

Hierarchy has many different granular values. However, those values are stored with reference to different versions in the db.

I.e.

1. Building an analysis with the different hierarchy elements (not the hierarchy itself) works great (granular values are automatically aggregated):

[image]

2. Building the same analysis only with the hierarchy itself, does not aggregate the granular values:

[image]

If possible, I want to change the settings in answers to automatically aggregate the values in the hierarchy, too.

Ideas and suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Your logical dimension and hierarchical object must be messed up to begin with. Does the actual level key include the version concept or "just" the member?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer. The actual level key includes the version concept - due to this input I figured out how to rebuild my dimension! Thanks!